# How to show data category wise using MySQl

Tags: php, mysql

This is my[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c3597) I am trying to show data in DataTables using this query but if I want to show data accordingly with each brand wise and category wise. What should I change in this query?

```
$q = intval($_POST['Name']);
$time = strtotime($_POST['Date']);
$day   = date('d',$time);
$month = date('m',$time);
$year  = date('Y',$time);
$query = "
SELECT d.distributor_name
     , s.order_date
     , p.product_name
     , s.nsp
     , s.current_sales
     , s.closing_balance
  FROM sales s
  LEFT 
  JOIN product p
    ON p.product_id = s.product_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN distributor d
    ON s.d_id = d.d_ID
 WHERE MONTH(s.order_date) =  '" . $month . "'  
   AND YEAR(s.order_date) = '" . $year . "' 
   AND d.d_id  = '" . $q . "';
";

$result = $connect->query($query);
$array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array['data'][] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($array);
$connect->close();
```

Comment: `What should I change in this query?` ... you should use prepared statements to build your query instead of raw string concatenation.  Show us the output you want to have.

Comment: Also, this query cannot use an index, whereas a range condition on the date could.

Comment: Oh, and d is an inner join.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this code is generating data in json, I added the complete code.